# moving files in a new folder in Python using shutil

Tags: python, shutil

I'm trying to do a simple script that iterates all the content in a folder and then if an element is a image it gets moved to a subfolder (inside the original folder) called `images`, while if it is video it gets moved in a subfolder (inside the original folder) called `videos`.
This is my code:

```
import os
import shutil

path = input('file path to sort: ')
list = os.listdir(path)

fin_img_path = os.mkdir(path+'\\images')
fin_vid_path = os.mkdir(path+'\\videos')

for i in list:
    print(i)
    if i.endswith('.jpg'):
        new_path = shutil.move(f"{path}/{i}", fin_img_path)
    elif i.endswith('.mp4') or i.endswith('.mkv'):
        new_path = shutil.move(f"{path}/{i}", fin_img_path)
    print(new_path)

print('images and videos divided')
```

However I get this error message:

```
file path to sort: C:\Users\utente\Pictures\Saved Pictures\Images_Videos
1.jpg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\vscode\PYTHON\image-videos.py", line 13, in <module>
    new_path = shutil.move(f"{path}/{i}", fin_img_path)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\shutil.py", line 791, in move
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\genericpath.py", line 42, in isdir
    st = os.stat(s)
TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not NoneType
```

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Easier to just do it in the shell.  `cd <path>`, `md images`, `move *.jpg images`, etc.

Comment: @MarkTolonen their approach is more OS agnostic

Comment: @Chris_Rands Of course, but sounds like a one-time job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.mkdir()` is a procedural call and returns `None`, hence your error. You need to feed the name of the file path instead to `shutil.move()`, e.g.

```
fin_img_path = path+'\\images'
fin_vid_path = path+'\\videos'
os.mkdir(fin_img_path)
os.mkdir(fin_vid_path)
```